# How to customize tab bar item image on runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, uitabbaritem

I need to change the image of the tab bar item based on one of the option selected in my first tab at runtime. Whenever user changes the option the tab bar item image should change.

For example: I have 3 tabs. In first tab I have following options:
"Red"
"Green"
"Blue"

According to the option which user selects, the tab bar item image should change. (ie. for red, all 3 tabs should have red icons and so on)

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Have you read the "Customizing Appearance" section of the UITabBarItem class reference?

Comment: Yes. I read. But not getting what is required